# Updating the value to a attribute of a class from an output of a method

Tags: python, oop, methods, syntax-error, python-dataclasses

I am doing object oriented programming and quite new to it. I have multiple classes and methods in them are all interrelated. Now when I try to update the value of an attribute of a class using the output of one of the method, I am unable to rectify, if my syntax works fine.

Below is the snippet of my code:

classes:

```py
@dataclass
class ProductionTask:
    id: int
    processingtime: int
    duration: float
    done: bool
    start_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    end_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    production_equipment: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG


@dataclass
class TransferTask:
    id: int
    min_transfer_duration: float
    max_transfer_duration: float
    done: bool
    start_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    end_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    equipment_item: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG

@dataclass
class ProductionEquipment:
    id: int
    production_tasks: List[ProductionTask] | None = None
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG


@dataclass
class TransferEquipment:
    id: int
    transfer_tasks: List[TransferTask] | None = None
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG

@dataclass
class Stage:
    id: int
    production_equipment: List[ProductionEquipment] | None = None
    transfer_equipment: List[TransferEquipment] | None = None
```

There are various methods in the stage class like below:

```py
def production_equipment_available(self, time):
    if self.id > 1:
        if self.production_equipment is not None:
            for equipment in self.production_equipment:
                if equipment.production_tasks is not None:
                    if all(
                        (
                            task.end_time < time
                            for task in equipment.production_tasks
                        )
                    ):
                        available = True
                    else:
                        available = False
                    return available


def transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks(self):
    production_task_ids = self.unassigned_production_tasks_in_stage2and3()
    transfer_task_ids = self.completed_transfer_tasks(self._time)
    for id in production_task_ids:
        if id in transfer_task_ids:
            return id
    return None
```

However, I am not getting expected results. I am not sure where is the syntax being wrong. What I intend to do?

- The output of `transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks` is `2` suppose. Also the output of the `production_equipment_available` is True. Also can I return the id of the equipment which is available?
- I want to append the `task 2` to the `equipment id` which is available. By that I mean, the attribute `start_time` of that task should be the the time I assigned it to available equipment.

Comment: What is `equipment.production_tasks` supposed to be? I'm betting you want `if equipment is not None:` not `if equipment.production_tasks is not None:`. Also check what `start_time` is (i.e. `print(start_time)`), maybe it's `None`. Same with `task.start_time`

Comment: Why the `assign_production_task` function get `ids` as input? While it is overwritten in the function before its usage.

Comment: Secondly, there is a potential syntax typo you have in the `assign_production_task`. What is `task.start_time==time`? If you want assign `time` to `task.start_time` you should do it like this: `task.start_time = time`. Otherwise, if you want check the equality of `time` and `task.start_time`, you should use that somewhere in the code.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi The output of `transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks` is 2. That is actually `task.id` . So How do I use that as an argument to `assign_production_task`?

Comment: For that, you can pass the output of `transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks` to `assign_production_task`. Like this: `self.transfer_task_passed_minimum_from_unassigned_production_tasks(ids=self.assign_production_task(...), time=self._time)`

Comment: Hi @AmirrezaRiahi, Can we use chat ?